# Finding the magnetic field given the electric field

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm reading a book on Electricity and Magnetism. I was solving some problems and found this very interesting one:

> WARNING: The next problems don't have to be solved applying Maxwell's equations; rather, it's required to cogitate about the physical situation.
>
> There is a vacuum region where an electric field is defined as $\boldsymbol E=\langle A\sin\beta y\sin\omega t ,0,0\rangle$. Determine the magnetic field, evaluate $\beta$ and show that this field is a combination of travelling waves. Also, show the direction of propagation.

So (I lack of physical intuition and experience in electrodynamics), I will take into account the equations $$ \nabla\times \boldsymbol B = \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t},~~~~\nabla\times\boldsymbol E = -\frac{\partial \boldsymbol B}{\partial t},~~~~ \nabla\cdot\boldsymbol B = 0.$$

I end up with $\boldsymbol B = \frac{A\beta}{\omega}\sin\beta y\cos\omega t \boldsymbol{\hat k}+\boldsymbol f(x,y,z),$ where $\boldsymbol f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$. So I have a bunch of partial derivatives of $\boldsymbol f$ and of course I can't solve them as the warning adviced. Can you give me any hint that would lead me any further in solving this interesting problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @KyleKanos I know that but this is the only site where I know people can help me in a good manner. I already got an answer, shall I delete this answer or wait until the moderators close it? Sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: I thought this was an okay homework-like problem because it asks "how can I apply physical intuition to this situation?" rather than "what is the answer?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice physical intuition problem.  Here's a kick along the intended path.

A plane wave with frequency $\omega$ traveling along a wavevector $\mathbf k$ has the form $\cos\left( \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf x - \omega t \right)$.  Working backwards from the identity $$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B$$ we find the electric field
$$
 E_x = 
\frac A2 \cos( -\beta y - \omega t ) - \frac A2 \cos( +\beta y - \omega t).
$$
This is a superposition of two plane waves traveling along the $\pm y$ directions.

The Poynting vector $\mathbf S \propto \mathbf E \times \mathbf B$ tells us that for an EM plane wave $\mathbf E, \mathbf B, \mathbf k$ form a right-handed coordinate system with $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ oscillating in phase.  You can use this to find the components of $\mathbf B$ for both of the plane waves, and recombine them using the same trig identity.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read a bit about that Poynting vector! But just to be sure: we CONSTRUCT the electromagnetic wave (because it is a solution for the Maxwell's equations). Is this EM plane wave the only solution to the problem?

Comment: @VladimirVargas I think it's the only solution with nonzero curl; there could be a constant magnetic field pointing in any direction.